# Execute condition inside infinite while loop only once

Tags: bash, shell

So, I have a bash script which has an infinite while loop. The code is:

```
counter = 0
while :; do
    if pgrep -x "gedit" > /dev/null; then
        echo "running"
    else
        counter=$((counter+1))
        if ["$counter" -eq "0"]; then
            cd /path/
            python3 filename.py
        fi
    fi
    sleep 10
done
```

The "if" statement is okay. But the "else" statement has a python script in it which makes a file when it runs. Now in this code the file is created again and again. I want the file to be created only once per else statement execution.

I am confused where am I going wrong?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing spaces around the brackets.

Comment: Change your thinking a bit.  It sounds like what you really want is to run the python script only if the file does not exist.

Comment: `The "if" statement is okay` - it isn't, I believe there is no such command as `[0` on your system.

Comment: Also, `counter=0` without spaces around the `=`.

Comment: Why is the Python script inside the loop at all? Do you only want to run it the first time `gedit` is not running?

Comment: @chepner Yes, I want to run it first time gedit is not running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need or want a counter, you just need a flag:

```
unset python_executed
while :; do
    if pgrep -x "gedit" > /dev/null; then
        echo "running"
        unset python_executed
    elif test -z "$python_executed"; then
        ...
        python_executed=1
    fi
    sleep 10
done
```

But really it sounds like you want to check for the existence of a file rather than worrying about which iteration of the loop you're in.

Comment: Yes I want the file to be created everytime an instance of gedit runs and then stops.

Comment: @Jishan . Huh?  The question is how to prevent it from running.  But now it sounds like what you want is to simply move the "unset" into the first if condition.

Comment: Yes, this works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need spaces around the square braces of the if statement.  Also you're incrementing the counter before you check it so you'll never hit the case if when the syntax is correct.  This should work:

```
counter = 0
while :; do
    if pgrep -x "gedit" > /dev/null; then
        echo "running"
    else
        counter=$((counter+1))
        if [ "$counter" -eq "1" ]; then
            cd /path/
            python3 filename.py
        fi
    fi
    sleep 10
done
```